# Ftp upload file in perticular path by android

Tags: android, upload, path, ftp

```
    f.connect("ftp.drivehq.com",21);
        if(f.login("XXXX", "XXX"))
        {
        f.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        f.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(URL);
        result = f.storeFile(newfile, in);
        in.close();
        f.logout(); 
        f.disconnect();
        }
    It upload fine but not in particular path i also try as ftp://ftp.drivehq.com/myfolder
```

but it gives error in android unknown host exception like I need to upload file in particular folder So thanks in advance help me

Comment: please post your logcat file

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please use the following code. it worked for me i have checked it.

```
SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();

         try
         {
            // Connect to an FTP server on port 21.

            ftp.connect("host", 21, "username", "password");

            // Set binary mode.
            ftp.bin();

            // Change to a new working directory on the FTP server.


            ftp.cwd("/httpdocs/yourdestinationfolderinftp");

            // Upload some files.
            ftp.stor(new File("/mnt/sdcard/ftp.jpg"));              

            // Quit from the FTP server.
            ftp.disconnect();

         }
         catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
             e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```